# UIAlert and push segues

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an IF statement that checks labels to see if a label is empty, if it is show an alert.

```
  if ([_DOBDate.text length] == 0) 
    {

    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cannot Proceed"
                                                      message:@"Please Submit your DOB and Gender"
                                                     delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [message show];
    }
```

later on in the function I have perform segue, like this :

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SetUptoMain" sender:self];
```

True, the alert does fire when the label is blank, but it also performs the segue. This perform segue line is not in the IF statement. So I would have thought it would have ran the IF statement and stayed there till I pressed OK. OK would be staying on the same view controller.

The segue is performed, is this due to Blocks ? any advice ?

So if the USER pressed Ok from the UIAlert the VC does not move, it stays where it was so the user can enter the details required.

This is my code :

```
- (IBAction)SettingsSave:(id)sender {

    if ([_DOBDate.text length] == 0) 
    {

    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cannot Proceed"
                                                      message:@"Please Submit your DOB and Gender"
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [message show];
    }
```

more code...
then at the end

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SetUptoMain" sender:self];

}
```

thanks

Comment: When do you call this code? In a `IBAction` method? Do you know the `if/else` logic/implementation?

Comment: I run this is an IBACTION method, yes! So it first checks to see if an label is blank. If it is run the UIAlert. Then it does code and then it performs a segue. If the label is blank I want it to show the alert view and stay in that VC so when the user pressed OK they can add details

Comment: From your update it sounds like you just need to put your perform segue inside an else... if() { show alert view} else { perform segue }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an `if/else` logic issue. Read about it.

```
-(IBAction)yourAction:(id)sender
{
    if ([_DOBDate.text length] == 0)
    {
       //Show your AlertView as you did
    }
    else
    {
        //put the rest of your code, including the performSegue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIAlertView` doesn't block execution.  It runs **asynchronously**.  Therefore the code path will go into your `if statement`, then continue past it.

If you only want the **segue** to be performed after the user presses the **alert view** button then you need to implement `UIAlertViewDelegate`.

In your header file add something like this:

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

When you create the **alert view** do it like this:

```
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Cannot Proceed"
                                                      message: @"Please Submit your DOB and Gender"
                                                     delegate: self
                                            cancelButtonTitle: @"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles: nil];

[message show];
```

And add this method to implement the `UIAlertViewDelegate`.

```
- (void) alertView: (UIAlertView *) alertView clickedButtonAtIndex: (NSInteger) buttonIndex {

    // perform segue here.  You can also check what button was pressed based on the button index.
}
```

Comment: I answer the same thin, but it seems (see the edit) that is not the user issue.